# Error in stored procedure : Cannot apply inner join

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

**Solved**

- Replace : `vs.VehicleStatus VehicleStatus`
- With : `max(vs.VehicleStatus) VehicleStatus`

I am new in this field kindly help by elaborating the issue.

**Error :**

> Procedure sp_VRMS_VehicleRequest_getvehiclerequestsgrouped, Line 25
>   Column 'VRMS_VehicleStatus.VehicleStatus' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Stored procedure query:

```
SELECT max([VehicleRequestID]) VehicleRequestID
      ,[AdminId]
      ,max([DesireCarTypeId]) DesireCarTypeId
      ,max([AssignCarTypeId]) AssignCarTypeId
      ,max([Source]) Source 
      ,max([Destination]) Destination
      ,max([Landmark]) Landmark
      ,max([NumberOfPassenger]) NumberOfPassenger
      ,CASE WHEN max([PickUpTIme])= min([PickUpTIme]) THEN null ELSE max([PickUpTIme]) END PickUpTill
      ,min([PickUpTIme]) PickUpTIme
      ,[BookingDate]
      ,max([CarNumber]) CarNumber
      ,max([DriverName]) DriverName
      ,max([DriverMobile]) DriverMobile
      ,max([AllocationDate]) AllocationDate
      ,vs.VehicleStatus VehicleStatus
      ,max([Remarks]) Remarks
      ,max([CRFTRF]) CRFTRF
      ,max([CostCentreNo]) CostCentreNo
      ,max([DutyDetails]) DutyDetails
  FROM 
      [dbo].[VRMS_VehicleRequest] As vr 
  INNER JOIN 
      VRMS_VehicleStatus as vs on vr.VehicleStatusID = vs.VehicleStatusID 
  GROUP BY 
     AdminId, Bookingdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `vs.VehicleStatus` in group by clause, like this:

```
group by AdminId,Bookingdate,vs.VehicleStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

**"The aggregate function requirement for non-grouped columns is not some arbitrary syntax restriction of SQL in general or of SQL Server's implementation!"** It is simple logic, like dividing by zero -- it must be handled and dealt with explicitly, whether we are writing SQL or working it out on paper by hand...

The above is an excerpt of **[this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx)** article. Read it and it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note when you are applying GroupBy clause, make sure that all the columns which are in the select statement should be either in aggregate function i.e. max, Min, Count, Sum, Avg etc or they should be in your group by clause. So, you should add vs.VehicleStatus column in your group by clause i.e. Group By AdminId, BookingDate,vs.VehicleStatus. I hope this helps.